# C# Resize picturebox with timer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am not very good at this, but I have an idea, and I want to ask here if it is possible. So I want to make, so PictureBox grows bigger, grows to some size and then goes smaller again, and continue doing this. I have only figured out how to make, so it goes bigger or smaller, but I can not figure out how to make so it detects specific size, and then do the opposite. The code I use.

```
Size size = pictureBox.Size;
size.Height--;
size.Width--;
pictureBox.Size = size;
```

Comment: Yes using a Timer is a good option. Search how to use them and if you have problems ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an example, since you didn't specify your criterion for enlarging and reducing. Initialize your timer:

```
// set the interval you prefer
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(500); 
timer.Elapsed += OnElapsed;
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

Create a member variable that controls whether the `PictureBox` must be enlarged or reduced:

```
private Boolean m_Reducing = false;
```

And then put everything together in your subscribed timer handler:

```
private static void OnElapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Size size = pictureBox.Size;

    if (m_Reducing)
    {
        --size.Height;
        --size.Width;

        if ((size.Width == minimumWidth) && (size.Height == minimumHeight))
            m_Reducing = false;
    }
    else
    {
        ++size.Height;
        ++size.Width;

        if ((size.Width == maximumWidth) && (size.Height == maximumHeight))
            m_Reducing = true;
    }

    pictureBox.Size = size;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, dude! It is just what I was imagining!

Comment: Care. because this can be kinda intensive for your interface...